# creating custom objects using google realtime api

Tags: javascript, kineticjs, google-drive-realtime-api

I try to connect my kineticjs script with google realtime but i don't understand how to  create custom collaborative objects in google realtime to make my app synchronous.

Does anyone know how to create a custom object  with google realtime api.

Furthermore, if any examples are available it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well i found this example with custom objects https://realtimeplayground.appspot.com/